# How do I write a function to do parallel computation without using a Promise?

Tags: javascript

I have the following task: *"Write a function to perform parallel computations without using Promise."*

There is a code example of how this should work.
I need to write a `paralell` function, but I don't quite understand how it can be done.

```
const first = function(a, b) {
  return a + b
}
const second = function() {
  return false;
}
paralell([[first, [3, 4]], [second]], function(res) {
    console.log(res); // [7, false]
});
```

Comment: What does "parallel" mean here?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout()`. You can use WebWorkers.

Comment: @VLAZ operations that are performed simultaneously

Comment: @argentonik see, that's the problem. Promises aren't parallel. And a valid implementation for your function would be `parallel = (arr, cb) => cb(arr.map(([f, xs]) => f.apply(null, xs)))`. But it's also not happening simultaneously.

Comment: @VLAZ perhaps it also means that I need to run the second function without waiting for the first function to finish. with promises it would probably work something like this Promise.all (...)

Comment: Actually, it is not possible because javascript is monothread... but it can be done using node's multithread

Comment: @argentonik promises are not parallel. They are just a notification mechanism for asynchronous operations. In many, many cases async code doesn't mean "runs in a separate thread" or anything similar to that - a lot of async functions run on the same exact thread as all the other functions. So, they would still be processed in sequence, rather than simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you need truly parallel processing, you'll need to run different parts of the code in separate environments. You can create a worker thread for each parallel process, or send a request to a server for the server to do it.

For the worker approach, you'll have to serialize the functions, which means the functions should not depend on external variables:

```js
const parallel = (arr, cb) => {
  const results = {};
  arr.forEach(([fn, args], i) => {
    const workerFnStr = `(${fn})();`;
    const blob = new Blob([workerFnStr], { type: 'text/javascript' });
    const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    worker.onmessage = (e) => {
      results[i] = e.data;
      if (Object.keys(results).length === arr.length) {
        cb(Object.values(results));
      }
    };
    worker.postMessage(args);
  });
};

const first = function() {
  self.onmessage = (e) => {
    const [a, b] = e.data;
    self.postMessage(a + b);
  };
};
const second = function() {
  self.onmessage = (e) => {
    self.postMessage(false);
  };
};
parallel([[first, [3, 4]], [second]], function(res) {
    console.log(res); // [7, false]
});
```